# Retrieve Source for a Tag with PHP DOMElement Object

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

Is there a way to retrieve the raw tag source for a `DOMElement` instance? I've gotten a list of nodes matching an XPath query using `DOMXpath::query()`, and then have accessed a single `DOMElement` with `DOMNodeList::item($i)`. Essentially I want to get the tag source for `DOMElement` as a string like:

```
<tag attr1="whatever" attr2="somethingElse" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo $node->ownerDocument->saveXML($node);
```